# Error for setting the backgroundColor of a UITableHeaderFooterView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

I have a custom Header class for my tableviews and whenever it is used, I keep getting this error:

> [TableView] Setting the background color on UITableViewHeaderFooterView has been deprecated. Please set a custom UIView with your desired background color to the backgroundView property instead.

Here are some things I've tried:

I added a backgroundView in awakeFromNib() of UITableViewHeaderFooterView subclass:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.backgroundView = UIView(frame: self.bounds)
    self.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.84, green:0.47, blue:0.97, alpha:1.0)
}
```

I added a backgroundView in my tableView function that defines header sections:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    if let headerView = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: Header.identifier) as? Header {

        // Extraneous Code

        let backgroundView = UIView(frame: headerView.bounds)
        backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.5, alpha: 0.5)
        headerView.backgroundView = backgroundView

        // Extraneous code
    }
    return UIView()
}
```

After doing each of those, I still get the error.

Comment: You’re trying to return a new clean UIView(). Your views, that you setting up above, having no sence with that. Return your headerView in viewForHeader instead.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to prevent the errors from showing up. Here's how I did it:

Go to the Xib file of the header and for the background color choose default. Then, in viewForHeaderInSection function, add:

```
let backgroundView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.5, alpha: 0.5)
headerView.backgroundView = backgroundView
```

I know I mentioned it in my question, but the key was setting the xib background color as "default".

Answer (score 0):

Check you must be setting `headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.5, alpha: 0.5)`

in your `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?` function.

Also, this would be sufficient to add the background color

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
     let backgroundView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
     backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.5, alpha: 0.5)
     return backgroundView
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can subclass `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`, you may try this approach.

```
class SampleHeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        let bgView = UIView(color: .black)

        addSubview(bgView)

        bgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let layoutAttributes: [NSLayoutAttribute] = [.top, .leading, .bottom, .trailing]
        layoutAttributes.forEach { attribute in
            addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: bgView,
                                             attribute: attribute,
                                             relatedBy: .equal,
                                             toItem: self,
                                             attribute: attribute,
                                             multiplier: 1,
                                             constant: 0.0))
        }
    }
}

extension UIView {
    convenience init(color: UIColor) {
        self.init(frame: .zero)
        backgroundColor = color
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While using the name `backgroundView` aren't you getting an error as :

> 1) Ambiguous use of 'backgroundView'
>
> 2) Cannot override mutable property 'backgroundView''
>
> 3) Cannot override with a stored property 'backgroundView'

as you are not adding a `backgroundView` you are using the one that `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` have.

For `awakeFromNib`:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    let bgView = UIView(frame: self.bounds)
    bgView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.84, green:0.47, blue:0.97, alpha:1.0)
    self.addSubview(bgView)
}
```

For `viewForHeaderInSection`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    if let headerView = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: Header.identifier) as? Header {

    // Extraneous Code

        let bgView = UIView(frame: headerView.bounds)
        bgView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.5, alpha: 0.5)
        headerView.addSubview(bgView)

        return headerView
        // Extraneous code
    }
    return UIView()
}
```

You just have to change the name `backgroundView` to some other name.